# Silverlight OOB and Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-oauth, silverlight-oob

I have silverlight oob application and need to add Google OAuth 2.0
I'm using this [article](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=uk#formingtheurl) as reference:

I tried to use [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Control to send request to Google Auth Service.

Code sample is pretty simple

```
        var url = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
        redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
        response_type=code&
        scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&
        client_id=<my_client_id>");

        WebBrowser.Navigate(url);
```

But I keep getting this error `WebBrowser.Navigate Attempted to perform an unauthorized` operation.

I tried `http ://localhost` as  redirect_uri (result is the same)

Isthere any way to make this work in Silverlight App OOB Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found solution. Just need to check **Require Elevated trust when running outside the browser** in Out-of-Browser Settings.